# Read fluent data files on python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to read data from some files from a software called ANSYS Fluent on Python. I used with gzip.open to unzip the files but I am getting something which looks like this:

`(\xafDb\xcd}\xd7\xda\xbe\x144\xba\xac\t}\xc9>p\x97,\x97\x9e\x03\x01\xbf\xd9\x90}\xb3q\xfe\x07\xbfVRP\x1d\x94\xfb\x0f\xbf\x03R\xf8\xc8\xd8\xd3\x10\xbf!\xd0\xd6{\x7f\xc1\x0b\xbfS\x9e\xcc\xc9\xdej\xfa\xbe\xcb\x97k\x8f\xf4\xda\xbe\x8d\xbf\xcd\x80l\xb0\x07?\xb7\x8f\xa5\xbb\xd02\xc6\xbexi\xd0k!\xdd\xc0\xbe\xdb\x19;{B\x83\xf3\xbe\xf2c\xe8\x9bp\x8b\xff\xbe\xb8Yr\xa2\x85\xf4\x04\xbf\xa6\xc7\x99G\x8e<\x08\xbf\xa2\x88\xfe\x1b\x83\x1d\t\xbf9\x9beu\xd9\xad\x03\xbf&\x16 \x91R\xfd\xbe\\\xdeE\xd9\x99\xad\xe4>\xe8\x1c0_\x92\xfd\x80>\xcc\xfa\xdb\xc3qL\xd2>=\x81!\xf8\x1f\xa0\xdd>\xbbn\xa2Y\x08?\xe9>CG5\x1eZ\xfc\xef>6\xda\xd5vh\n`

Can anyone help?

Comment: So... This is it: assuming you ungzipped this correctly, you got a binary file, whose format could be described in the docs of this software, but it's probably not as it's probably not supposed to be read or modified outside ANSYS Fluent. Anyway, one can interpret these bytes in a whole lot of ways (as an executable, an image, a video, music, etc), so I think it's impossible to guess what kind of data it represents _without thoroughly examining the documentation_.

Comment: At the end of Fluent user's manual you can find the description of fluent file format.